# Have a data set for 3 consecutive days. What are my options?

Tags: forecasting, dataset, simulation, markov-process

Let's say I have a set regarding the transportation methods(Eg: car, bus, train) used for three consecutive days b y $n$ number of people. For simplicity let us assume that everyone use only one type of a transportation method on a given day so that we have only one data point for a single person for a given day. So the data set for few people would look like as follows. [image]

So can I do something meaningful (other than drawing bar charts, pie charts etc. ) with this data? If we have, say data of about 100 people of a certain region I thought of constructing a Markov chain which would lead me to a whole lot of options and results that can be used to predict the future behavior of people under certain assumptions of course.

What are the other methods like this that I can use to say something meaningful or to predict the future behavior just by using this data set? Can I use simulation to do something? I am not really familiar with simulation so any ideas related to that will also help me out a lot. Thanks in advance and hope the question is not confusing.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I'm curious: how can you apply a Markov chain to this case if you don't know the probability of a person to take a specific transportation method at each step (day)?

Comment: @JosephD'Arimathea Well we can take an approximation right? we have data for 3 days so 2 transitions. we can take on average how the transitions happen and get a matrix.

Comment: @JosephD'Arimathea to give more detail, say we take people who use a car on the 1st day then we can see how many of them change to train and how many change to bus and also how many remain using car on the second day as well. Soo there you go

Comment: Understood, so you analyse the behaviour of each person an derive the individual probability of taking Train, Bus or Car and then build a Markov Chain to predict, on average, how many people will take each transportation method each day over a long period of time. Do you really need a Markov Chain to do it? Wouldn't taking the average number of persons by transportation method suffice?

Comment: @JosephD'Arimathea Markov Chain is taken assuming the transitions would occur in the future same way it has occurred in the given data set, which would give a time homogeneous MC. Using a MC would tell us how the present day average (initial vector) would change according to the available data. It will tell us whether the current average would change considerably in the longrun or whether it would remain relatively the same. I think merely taking an average will not help out much but I am not saying the MC method is accurate but it is possible to apply it